# Apache Cassandra ordering bv clustering keys?

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have a table with this setup:

```
...
    PRIMARY KEY (id, "requestId", "createdAt")
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY ("requestId" ASC, "createdAt" DESC)
```

So when I run CQL like:

```
SELECT * from "Table" WHERE "requestId"='someId'
```

Should I get results ordered by createdAt DESC? That's what I would expect, but I'm new to Cassandra and am not sure about how this works.

What I want to achieve is to retrieve all records that belong a certain requestId, ordered by creation date DESC.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

In Cassandra, data is ordered only inside the partition, not globally. If you do `SELECT * from "Table" WHERE id = .... AND "requestId"='someId'`, then you will get data by `createdAt` in descending order

Your original query won't work out of box because you don't have the partition key provided.  And if you put "ALLOW FILTERING" (bad idea), then you will get data back, but ordered by `createdAt` inside each partition separately.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.  I don't get it: SELECT * from "Table" WHERE id = .... AND "requestId"='someId' would return things in the right order. But that's just one record right? I mean each id is unique.
So how I provide a partition key?

Comment: @user2297996 then it sounds like the table should probably be rebuilt with `requestId` as the partition key.  Assuming of course, that there are not too many `createdAt`s per `requestId`.  A 100% unique partition key distributes well, but doesn't let you take advantage of Cassandra's wide-rows.

Comment: Aaron is correct - in Cassandra, tables are modeled around queries. I recommend to read first chapters from this free book to understand how to model data for Cassandra: https://www.datastax.com/resources/ebook/oreilly-cassandra-definitive-guide